# Reset a java variable Instant type to zero or clear it

Tags: java, duration, java-time, java.time.instant

I'm implementing some services in JAVA to a call center. I need to record the duration of a call so I'm using this to do that:

```
last = Instant.now();
Duration duration = Duration.between(first, last);
tfinal=Timestamp.from(last);
Long minutos;
Long hours;
duracion = "00 horas y ";
minutos = duration.toMinutes();
if (minutos > 60) {
    hours = duration.toHours();
    duracion = hours.toString() + " horas y ";
}
duracion = duracion + minutos.toString() + " minutos";
```

Which works perfectly...the thing is I have a *cancel* button on my screen which cleans all my fields or reset them to 0....What I haven´t figure out is how to return my  *last* variable to 0... or something that clears this field which contains my *last* Instant type variable. I can set to "" my *duracion* variable because it is a String...but how can I achieve this with my java.time.Instant variabale?  I'm also using *primefaces*.

Comment: I know, I was about to write "but that's irrelevant" :3

Comment: This may sound like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What makes you think you need to clear `last`? If you keep `last` local to the method where you use it, I guess it would eliminate any problem with clearing it, is that right?

Comment: As an aside I don’t think your code works perfectly. With a duration of 70 minutes I get a `duracion` of `1 horas y 70 minutos` — not intended, was it? BTW I find it confusing to have variables `duration` and `duracion`, don’t you?

Comment: To answer the question, there is no such thing as a zero or emtpy `Instant`. You may set the varialbe to `null`, of course, you just need to make sure that your code can handle that. I don’t think it’s the best solution. Not knowing your design it’s hard to give better suggestions.

Comment: That's right, if I keep `last` local I will not have to clear it. The thing is I am displaying it in the view. I have to display The initial time, the end time and the duration of the call. When you just mentioned  "there is no such thing as a zero or empty Instant" I just realized how silly it sounds to _empty_ an  `Instant` -.-  I guess I will have to do the thing I was avoiding: create another variable which stores only the string value and can be cleared. x_x

Comment: And yes, you're right, the approach for the minutes-hours problem is just sad x_x ... I haven´t realized either, I think I need some sleep (haha!) thank you @Ole V.V. ...